# php Curl posting to PHPBB

Tags: php, curl

I used to post updates to a forum though a PHP script though my account, Recently it has stopped working, and im not 100% sure why - there are no errors returned by curl and everything *seems* to be ok apart from the message appearing.

The board im posting to has disable flood limit set for my user and I have permissions to post what ever type of topic is needed

the code to post im using is the following (found online a while ago - minor edits)

```
$url = "http://url.co.uk/board/";

$post_fields = 'username=user&password=pass&redirect=&login=Log+in';
$lurl = $url."ucp.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$lurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$sid1 = explode("sid=",$result);
$sid2 = explode('&',$sid1[1]);
$sid = rtrim(substr($sid2[0], 0, -29),'"');

$purl = url&"posting.php?mode=post&f=20&sid=$sid";
var_dump($purl);
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$purl);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
$result1= curl_exec ($ch1);
curl_close ($ch1);

preg_match('%name="form_token" value="(.*)"\ /\>%',$result1,$security123);
preg_match('%name="lastclick" value="(.*)"\ /\>%',$result1,$lastclick);
preg_match('%name="creation_time" value="(.*)"\ /\>%',$result1,$ctime1);
$lclick = explode('" />',$lastclick[1]);

$title = "title";
$subject = "subject to post";
$post_fields = array(
            'subject'   => $title,
         'message'   => htmlspecialchars_decode($subject),
            'icon'      => 0,
'poll_title' => "Poll Name",
'poll_option_text' => "poll 1\r\npoll 2",
'poll_max_options' => 1,
'poll_length' => 0,
'poll_vote_change' => "on",


            'disable_smilies'   => 0,
            'attach_sig'        => 1,
            'notify'           => 0,
         'topic_type'         => 2,
            'topic_time_limit'   => "",
           'creation_time'      => $ctime1[1],
         'lastclick'          => $lclick[0],
          'form_token'   => $security123[1],
              'sid'     =>  $sid,
         'post'   => 'Submit',

         );
print_r($post_fields);
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$purl);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
$result2= curl_exec ($ch1);
if(curl_errno($ch1))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch1);
}
curl_close ($ch1);
echo $result2;
```

From this `$result2` has the output threads from the forum, But the message submitted hasnt been posted.

I am logged in ok in $result2 with no error messages visible.

Any suggestions ? ive checked sid, form_token, lclick and creation_time and they all *seem* to be the same and correct.

curl verbose output

```
* About to connect() to site.co.uk port 80
*   Trying 78.xxx.yyy.zzz... * connected
* Connected to site.co.uk (78.xxx.yyy.zzz) port 80
> POST /board/posting.php?mode=post&f=20 HTTP/1.1

Host: site.co.uk

Accept: */*

Cookie: phpbb3_9g61k_sid=693813912f38db33091212ee14102026; phpbb3_9g61k_k=; phpbb3_9g61k_u=57

Content-Length: 1914

Expect: 100-continue

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------2fb596b13df0



< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found

< Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 23:21:39 GMT

< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (CentOS)

< Location: http://site.co.uk/board/viewforum.php?f=20

< Content-Length: 0

< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

* Connection #0 to host site.co.uk left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://site.co.uk/board/viewforum.php?f=20'
* Disables POST, goes with GET
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host site.co.uk
* Connected to site.co.uk (78.xxx.yyy.zzz) port 80
> GET /board/viewforum.php?f=20 HTTP/1.1

Host: site.co.uk

Accept: */*

Cookie: phpbb3_9g61k_sid=693813912f38db33091212ee14102026; phpbb3_9g61k_k=; phpbb3_9g61k_u=57



< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

< Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 23:21:39 GMT

< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (CentOS)

< Cache-Control: private, no-cache="set-cookie"

< Expires: 0

< Pragma: no-cache

< Transfer-Encoding: chunked

< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

* Connection #0 to host site.co.uk left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Is it your forum, or someone else's? Maybe they blocked you.

Comment: Not blocked, I have admin access on forum, Not file access though. Nothing showing in any of the logs and i can see my user name appear online when script is run

Comment: if you are admin of this forum why not insert it direct to database instead use curl?

Comment: @QuyNguyen the database structure is very complex. is is very difficult to manually insert posts in PhpBB3.x databases

Comment: Not only that. But cache invalidation happens though the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it

posting.php line 49

```
if ($cancel || ($current_time - $lastclick < 2 && $submit))
```

Although flood is disabled for my user there is still a hard coded delay of 2 seconds that i have to stick to.

Comment: this sounds like a bug in PhpBB! to the bugtracker you should go

Comment: the file is not designed as an API endpoint (you see the OP question hacking the CSRF token from the page). This is a feature to prevent double posts by clicking the button twice in quick succession.